# Correct way to perform other actions after validating token from header in express

Tags: angular, http, express, ionic-framework

I'm with a big issue to get a middleware working for my endpoints. I'm trying to authenticate the request with a token from the header but it isn't working at all. Tried everyting and a lot of tutorials.
Additionally, I'm trying to test it on my mobile and browser and it doesn't work (when testing on mobile I'm hosting the server to heroku)

Im trying to communicate between the client, in angular, and my express endpoint.
here it is in angular:

```
getFloorInfo(floorid){

    //get the token
    var token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    //set header
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('x-access-token', token);

    //set request options
    let options = new RequestOptions( {method: RequestMethod.Options, headers: headers });

    //send request
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/floor/',{
        id: floorid
    }, options)


  }
```

this is my header config on express

```
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS,POST,GET,PUT,DELETE");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, x-access-token");
    next();
  });
```

this is my express endpoint

```
locations.post('/floor_information',function (req, res, next) {


    var token = req.body.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    if (token) {

      jwt.verify(token, app.get('mysecretbuddy'), function(err, decoded) {          
        if (err) {
          console.log('token err', err);
          return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });        
        } else {

             // get the value from the body
                var floor = db.escape(req.body.floor);

                db.getConnection(function(err, connection){
                if(err) return console.log(err);

                    const sql = 'SELECT FloorInfo WHERE ID = ?';

                                    const values = [floor]

                                        //query db
                                    db.query(sql, values, function (error, results, fields){

                                        connection.release();

                                        if(error){

                                        console.log(error);

                                        }else{

                                        res.send(results);

                                        }


                                    })


                })

          req.decoded = decoded;
          next();

        }
      });

    } else {

      return res.status(403).send({ 
        success: false, 
        message: 'No token provided.'
      });

    }

  });
```

I want this query to be performed after the token is checked from the header.

now my question is, how would I call the query to my db just after the token is checked? I've tried it here but I didn't get the function of next() very well. Can someone help?

the funny thing is that when using postman it works, but even testing on my phone or on the browser it didn't work at all. Please help!

i'm aware I can get a middleware for multiple endpoints, i've tried that too but I'm getting cors and it's impossible to configure. but I'm willing to understand how it works under the hood in a plain function so I can refactor later.

---

Found a solution that made it work the only way. Can you tell me if it's the best approach? Should I do this to every endpoint? How could I scale it?

```
floors.post('/floor_information',function (req, res, next) {


  // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
  var token = req.body.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

  // decode token
  if (token) {

    // verifies secret and checks exp
    jwt.verify(token, app.get('mysecretbuddy'), function(err, decoded) {            
      if (err) {
        return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });      
      } else {
        // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
        req.decoded = decoded;
        next();

      }
    });

  } else {

    // if there is no token
    // return an error
    return res.status(403).send({ 
      success: false, 
      message: 'No token provided.'
    });

  }

});

floors.post('/floor_information',function (req, res, next) {

  location.getFloorInfo(req,res,next)


});
```

Comment: In your `getFloorInfo` function you have a comment that says *send request*, but the fact is, until something subscribes to the observable that the function returns, nothing will happen. Are you subscribing to the observable somewhere?

Comment: Yes @R.Richards! I'm subscribing to it from my component. getFloorInfo is at a provider.

Comment: Anyways this is the message I get logging the `res` from `.subscribe()`. `Response {_body: "{"success":false,"message":"Failed to authenticate token."}", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …}` @R.Richards

Comment: I mean, it is not "nexting"

Comment: The error message is from the service. Seems your `jwt.verify` function is not working quite right. Looks like the token is truthy, but just isn't verifying. Are you certain you are using `jwt.verify` properly?

Comment: @R.Richards that's funny because when I use Postman it works great

Comment: Then I would say the token you are using in your app is not validating. Is it different from the one you are using with postman.

Comment: @R.Richards can you see the updated question? Found a solution to server side that works but I don't know if it's the best. Also, on the client side I had to call `.map(res=>res.json())`

Comment: I am no express expert, but the code seems reasonable to me. Nothing raises and red flags. Go with it. Glad you found something that works!

Comment: Thank you for the help @R.Richards !